# Hook or any other extension place for changing the input format order in form display?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms, input-formats

I want to change the order of the input formats (e.g. input format "rich text" comes before "text" in content type "article") in the node form field display. Could you recommend me a hook or any other place for my own code extension, please?

I do not want to use the better formats module for this, because I need this only for a few fields and this module is not stable, yet.

I have tried hook_field_widget_form_alter(), but it seems for me to be not the right place.

Comment: Each input format as a weight that can be changed from the user interface. Do you really need to do it programmatically?

Comment: I need to change the weight per content type. So yes: I need a few lines.